# multiple filter is not working in r somehow and it keeps on throwing error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to apply the multiple filter (daterange and selectinput filter together) and I have tried couple of methods like passing multiple conditions in filter function by using | and one of the method that I have given below. but somehow it is throwing error, I don't know why it is happening, could anyone please, guide me through what I am really missing here ,I wanna filter the graph by both the date and selectinput filter.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(htmltools)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)
total<-tibble::tribble(
         ~`B-25601`,  ~Order_Date, ~CustomerName,              ~State,                ~City, ~sales,
          "B-25602",   "1/4/2018",      "Bharat",           "Gujarat",          "Ahmedabad",  1275L,
          "B-25603",   "1/4/2018",       "Pearl",       "Maharashtra",               "Pune",    66L,
          "B-25604",   "3/4/2018",       "Jahan",    "Madhya Pradesh",             "Bhopal",     8L,
          "B-25605",   "3/4/2018",      "Divsha",         "Rajasthan",             "Jaipur",    80L,
          "B-25606",   "5/4/2018",     "Kasheen",       "West Bengal",            "Kolkata",   168L,
          "B-25607",   "6/4/2018",       "Hazel",         "Karnataka",          "Bangalore",   424L,
          "B-25608",   "6/4/2018",    "Sonakshi", "Jammu and Kashmir",            "Kashmir",  2617L,
          "B-25609",   "8/4/2018",     "Aarushi",        "Tamil Nadu",            "Chennai",   561L,
          "B-25610",   "9/4/2018",      "Jitesh",     "Uttar Pradesh",            "Lucknow",   119L,
          "B-25611",   "9/4/2018",      "Yogesh",             "Bihar",              "Patna",  1355L,
          "B-25612",  "11/4/2018",       "Anita",            "Kerala", "Thiruvananthapuram",    24L,
          "B-25613",  "12/4/2018",   "Shrichand",            "Punjab",         "Chandigarh",   193L,
          "B-25614",  "12/4/2018",      "Mukesh",           "Haryana",         "Chandigarh",   180L,
          "B-25615", "13/04/2018",     "Vandana",  "Himachal Pradesh",              "Simla",   116L,
          "B-25616", "15/04/2018",      "Bhavna",            "Sikkim",            "Gangtok",   107L,
          "B-25617", "15/04/2018",       "Kanak",               "Goa",                "Goa",    12L,
          "B-25618", "17/04/2018",       "Sagar",          "Nagaland",             "Kohima",    38L,
          "B-25619", "18/04/2018",       "Manju",    "Andhra Pradesh",          "Hyderabad",    65L,
          "B-25620", "18/04/2018",      "Ramesh",           "Gujarat",          "Ahmedabad",   157L)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "date",
                 label = 'Date range',
                 start = "2018/4/1",
                 end = "2018/4/18",
                 min  = "2018/4/1",
                 max = "2018/4/18",
                 format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                 separator = "TO"),
      pickerInput(inputId = "st",label = "Select State",multiple = TRUE,options = list(
                    `actions-box` = TRUE,
                    `deselect-all-text` = "Deselect ALL",
                    `select-all-text` = "Select ALL",
                    `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                  ),selected = total$State[],choices = c(unique(total$State))))),
  dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(withLoader(
  plotlyOutput("state", height = 200),type = "html",loader = "loader4"))))
  axis_titles <- . %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title = "Sales"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    State <- reactiveVal()
    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State"), {
    State(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State")$x)
  })
    output$state <- renderPlotly({
    total$Order_Date <- dmy(total$Order_Date)
    re_filter <- total %>% filter(State %in% input$st) %>% 
    filter(between(total$Order_Date,as.Date(input$date[1]),as.Date(input$date[2]))) %>%
    group_by(State) %>%
    summarise(total_sales = sum(sales))
    plot_ly(data = re_filter,x = re_filter$State,y = re_filter$total_sales,type="bar",source = "State",marker =list(color = COL)) %>% 
    axis_titles() %>% 
    layout(title = "State")
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your question. You should be careful not use use `total$` in filter commands when piping data from total. Check the datatypes of the values you are trying to use to filter.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your marker color was not defined.  After I just gave it a red color, and fixed what @MrFlick stated, you get the output shown below.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  State <- reactiveVal()
  
  output$state <- renderPlotly({
    total$Order_Date <- dmy(total$Order_Date)
    re_filter <- total %>% filter(State %in% input$st) %>% 
      filter(between(Order_Date,as.Date(input$date[1]),as.Date(input$date[2]))) %>%
      group_by(State) %>%
      summarise(total_sales = sum(sales))
    plot_ly(data = re_filter,x = re_filter$State,y = re_filter$total_sales,type="bar",source = "State",marker =list(color = "red")) %>% 
      axis_titles() %>% 
      layout(title = "State")
  })
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State"), {
    State(event_data("plotly_click", source = "State")$x)
  })
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick and YBS for your help and this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again for your quick response and providing complete solution.